# Updating the value of a keyword by Core Service in SDL Tridion 2013

Tags: core-service, sdl-tridion

I am trying to update the value of a keyword by using Core service in SDL Tridion 2013. 
On saving the item with new value by the following code:

```
 Client.CheckOut(item.Id, false, new ReadOptions());
 item = Client.Save(item, new ReadOptions());
 Client.CheckIn(item.Id, true, "Scripted Update", new ReadOptions());
 Log.Info($"Successfully updated Item {item.Id}");
```

I get the following exception. Any idea why this is happening and how can I resolve this?

```
System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1 was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233087
  Message=Unable to cast object of type 'Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.Keyword' to type 'Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.VersionedItem'.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
    Server stack trace: 
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
    Exception rethrown at [0]: 
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
       at Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.ICoreService.UndoCheckOut(String id, Boolean permanentLock, ReadOptions readBackOptions)
       at Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.CoreServiceClient.UndoCheckOut(String id, Boolean permanentLock, ReadOptions readBackOptions)
       at BlackBoard.Tridion.Migration.CoreService.Helpers.CoreServiceHelper.SaveItem(IdentifiableObjectData item) in C:\Code\BBMigrationTool\BlackBoard.Tridion.Migration.CoreService\Helpers\CoreServiceHelper.cs:line 77
       at BBMigrationTool.Actions.MigrateAction.ProcessKeywordMigration(ICoreServiceHelper helper, String language, CategoryKeyword categoryKeyword) in C:\Code\BBMigrationTool\BBMigrationTool\Actions\Migrate.cs:line 58
       at BBMigrationTool.Actions.MigrateAction.Invoke(ICoreService client) in C:\Code\BBMigrationTool\BBMigrationTool\Actions\Migrate.cs:line 35
       at BBMigrationTool.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Code\BBMigrationTool\BBMigrationTool\Program.cs:line 77
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the class hierarchy in the API doc. 
Note: Keywords and VersionedItems are both RepositoryLocalObjects, but not all RepositoryLocalObjects are VersionedItems. Take a look in the CM GUI, you'll notice that you don't have versions on Keywords.

So I would suspect that the line where you make the assignment to the '`item`' variable is what's causing the problem:

```
 item = Client.Save(item, new ReadOptions());
```

My guess is that above the code you showed you declared `item` as a type which is a `VersionedItem` (e.g. a Component), Page, Schema, Template), but are now trying to cast it as a `Keyword`.

Answer (score 2):

As it turned out, Keyword is not versioned. So, the exception is the result of `Client.CheckOut(item.Id, false, new ReadOptions());`
line. To solve this problem, you just need to separate checkin and checkout commands for items that are not versioned.

Comment: You can also use the CoreService `Update` method. That works for all items: versioned, not versioned, repository-local or system-wide.

Answer (score 2):

The CheckOut (and CheckIn) method signature in CoreService returns a VersionedItemData, as shown below.

```
VersionedItemData CheckOut(
    string id,
    bool permanentLock,
    ReadOptions readBackOptions
)
```

If you try to checkout(or checkin) a Keyword (KeywordData) which does not inherit from VersionedItemData you will get an exception.

Instead just do:

```
 item = Client.Save(item, new ReadOptions());
 Log.Info($"Successfully updated Item {item.Id}");
```

More details can be found in the [API reference guides here](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-2301148A-E3EA-43EF-A2FC-7D3C9BAEE8FF)